# Python - Finding the list of words that occurs n times in the given file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, counter

I want to find a list of word which occurs n times(for example 200) in a given file. For this purpose I get the the each unique tokens in the file with the following code but I couldn't understand how can I get the ones with the condition of occuring n times.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

seen = list()
words = re.findall(r'[\w+]+', open('deneme.txt').read())
seen = Counter(words).most_common()
```

Output is:

```
[('Erke', 4), ('aç+Noun', 4), ('Antalya', 3), ('123', 3), ('ol+Verb', 3), ('Varol', 2), ('Koleji', 1), ('asdfsdf', 1), ('birak+Verb', 1)]
```

For example I want to get tokens with occuring of 3 times. How can I achieve this. I can't reach the number of occurance in the list.

Comment: An easier way to do this would be to create a dictionary of all of the words with a value of the count of each word, then look at your dictionary for all words the occur n times

Comment: [ (x,y) for (x,y) in your_array_element if y == 3 ]

Comment: @SPYBUG96 It's not any easier than list comprehension.  You still end up looping through the `dict`/`list` either way.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from collections import Counter
import re

seen = list()
words = re.findall(r'[\w+]+', open('deneme.txt').read())
seen = Counter(words).most_common()

print([w for w, c in seen if c == 3])
```

**Output**

```
 ['123', 'Antalya', 'ol+Verb']
```

Comment: `[e[0] for e in seen if e[1] == 3]` will be useful if your tuples in list have too many elements.

Comment: @RockyLi Under what circumstances would that happen?  [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) always produces tuples of width 2.